# Sort compressed data in hadoop

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, compression

So here is the situation, 
I want to see if applying sort (from map reduce examples) on a compressed file is more efficient than on the original file.
To run this experiment, I first launch randomtextwriter to generate a sequence file in hdfs (`file1`).

- Then I get back the result with `hdfs dfs -getmerge file1 file2`
- Then I compress file2 into file2.bz2
- I then put file2.bz2 into hdfs
- Finally I launch sort on file2.bz2 (in hdfs)

This throws an error Java heap space.
Which I definetely don't understand considering that the initial file size is less than 500Mo
and I have the following configurations

In yarn-site.xml

```
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
                <value>2048</value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
                <value>2048</value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
                <value>1024</value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
                <value>false</value>
        </property>
```

In mapred-site.xml

```
   <property>
            <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
            <value>2048</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
            <value>1024</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
            <value>1024</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
            <value>-Xmx2048m</value>
    </property>
```